# What do drivers have to do with modules?

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules, proc

I need to research and find out "which drivers are loaded on my system" using `/proc`.

In `/proc` there is a dir called "`driver`" so I thought that was it, but reading about it online, I saw I should also take look at my `modules` file.

Why? what do these have to do with each other?

Comment: Here's the documentation for the /proc filesystem: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/filesystems/proc.rst

Answer (score 0):

Linux kernel modules are extensions of the kernel that implement functionality including that of drivers. `/proc` contains information about your devices and modules. There's your connection.